# Using Require and then Use in a class

Tags: php, phpoffice

I am trying to create an excel file by invoking a class. This is a class that I have written and inside this class, I am trying to invoke the PHPOFFICE library that is already installed on my system. My code is as follows:

```
class createXls {
                
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
        
    public function createXl($loginid, $report_index, $header, $data, $fname)
    {
```

But I am unable to get this to work because clearly `require` cannot be placed outside the method. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: _"because clearly require cannot be placed outside the method"_ That's exactly where it should go. If you're using PSR autoloading, none of your class files should ever have a `require` in them. Also note, a `use` inside a class denotes a trait, a `use` outside a class denotes a namespace alias/import.

Comment: so I have the require outside the method in the code I have pasted.. why is it throwing a syntax error [ unexpected: require after { ...  ]

Comment: _If you're using PSR autoloading, none of your class files should ever have a require in them._